# How to check if a scoped_session is already closed

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to check in Python's SQLAlchemy if a `scoped_session` has already been closed? In other words check if the `session.close` method has already been called?

**Example**:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker()
session_maker.configure(...)

session = scoped_session(session_maker)

hasclosed = f(session) #should return False

session.close()

hasclosed = f(session) #should return True
```

evidently one can override the `close` method such that it holds such status, but I'm wondering if there is any builtin support for this.

Comment: Care to explain why you want to do this?

Comment: You can call [remove](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/a99a32d3d1669e1a66776b7e168119656e6aed02/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#scoping.py-80) or even registry.has().

Comment: @QuentinPradet: because I want to make sure `close` is called. For each session created, a thread is started that regularly checks if the session is closed. If not and a timeout is reached, the session is automatically closed by that thread.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy, but I thought the whole point of scoped_session is that it's thread-local? Also, it sounds like you're trying to patch bad code. Anyway, anything wrong with remove() or registry.has()?

Comment: In my case, I wanted to check if the session is still valid before running some code. While this is for normal sessions and not `scoped_sessions`, using `session.is_active` did the trick.